# How to count schemes and domains from URLs in Java

Tags: java

This is for a school assignment, where I have to take in a command line argument that holds files which hold URLs. If there is no command line argument, I have to take in an argument from standard input. I then have to report how many types of certain domains and schemes were present in these URLs, as well as report back how many lines were read in each file. The program should read lines until it reaches "end". I'm not getting the right output that I should be getting with it. It should be outputting the correct count of how many times something shows up. For example, if you input through the commandline a list containing "https://www.facebook.com/
                                              ftp://ftp.bls.gov/pub/special.requests/cpi/cpiai.txt
end" it should report back

> ">>Found one instance of https" ">>Found one instance of ftp" ">>Found
>   one instance of com" ">>Found one instance of gov"

However, I think that there might be a problem with either the counting or printing part.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    public class P1{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException{
      int httpCount=0;
      int httpsCount=0;
      int ftpCount=0;
      int schemeOtherCount=0;     
      int eduCount=0;
      int orgCount=0;
      int comCount=0;
      int domainOtherCount=0;
      int lineCount=0;
      int fileLineCount = 0;
      int totalLineCount = 0;
      String fileName = " ";

    outerloop:if(args.length > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        fileName = args[i];
        fileLineCount = 0;
        File theBestFileEver = new File(fileName);
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(theBestFileEver);
        while(fileScan.hasNextLine()){
        String fileHolder = fileScan.nextLine();
        if(fileHolder.equals("end")){
               break outerloop;
        } 
        URL argsURL = new URL(fileHolder);
        String almostDomain = argsURL.getHost();
        int lastPeriod = almostDomain.lastIndexOf(".");
        int end = almostDomain.length();
        String argsDomain = almostDomain.substring(lastPeriod+1, end);
        String argsScheme = argsURL.getProtocol();
            if(argsScheme.equals("http"))
               httpCount++;
            if(argsScheme.equals("https"))
                 httpsCount++;
            if(argsScheme.equals("ftp"))
                 ftpCount++;
            if(!argsScheme.equals("http") && !argsScheme.equals("https") && !argsScheme.equals("ftp"))
                 schemeOtherCount++;
            if(argsDomain.equals("edu"))
              eduCount++;
            if(argsDomain.equals("org"))
              orgCount++;
            if(argsDomain.equals("com"))
              comCount++;
           if(!argsDomain.equals("edu") && !argsDomain.equals("org") && !argsDomain.equals("com"))
              domainOtherCount++;
           fileLineCount++;
           totalLineCount++;
           if(fileLineCount == 1)
             System.out.println(">> Got " + fileLineCount + " line from " + fileName);
           if(fileLineCount != 1)
             System.out.println(">> Got " + fileLineCount + " lines from " + fileName);     
        }
        }
    }
      else{
        Scanner scanTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
        here: while(scanTwo.hasNextLine()){
       String scannedUrlTwo = scanTwo.nextLine(); 
          if(scannedUrlTwo.equals("end")){
            break here;
          }
          URL twoURL = new URL(scannedUrlTwo);
             lineCount++;
             String scheme = twoURL.getProtocol();
             String nearlyDomain = twoURL.getHost();
             int twoLastPeriod = nearlyDomain.lastIndexOf(".");
             int twoEnd = nearlyDomain.length();
             String domain = nearlyDomain.substring((twoLastPeriod+1) , twoEnd);
             if(scheme.equals("http"))
               httpCount++;
            if(scheme.equals("https"))
                 httpsCount++;
            if(scheme.equals("ftp"))
                 ftpCount++;
            if(!scheme.equals("http") && !scheme.equals("https") && !scheme.equals("ftp"))
                 schemeOtherCount++;
            if(domain.equals("edu"))
              eduCount++;
            if(domain.equals("org"))
              orgCount++;
            if(domain.equals("com"))
              comCount++;
           if(!domain.equals("edu") && !domain.equals("org") && !domain.equals("com"))
              domainOtherCount++;
             if(lineCount == 1)
               System.out.println(">> Got 1 line from standard input");
             if(lineCount != 1)
               System.out.println(">> Got " + lineCount + " lines from standard input");
             }
           }

      if(httpCount != 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + httpCount + " instances of http");
      if(httpCount == 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + httpCount + " instance of http");
      if(ftpCount != 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + ftpCount + " instances of ftp");
      if(ftpCount == 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + httpCount + " instance of http");
      if(httpsCount != 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + httpsCount + " instances of https");
      if(httpsCount == 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + httpCount + " instance of http");
      if(schemeOtherCount != 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + schemeOtherCount + " instances of other schemes");
      if(schemeOtherCount == 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + schemeOtherCount + " instance of other schemes");
      if(eduCount != 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + eduCount + " instances of edu");
      if(eduCount == 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + eduCount + " instance of edu");
      if(orgCount != 1)
      System.out.println(">> Found " + orgCount + " instances of org");
      if(orgCount == 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + orgCount + " instance of org");
      if(comCount != 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + comCount + " instances of com");
      if(comCount == 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + comCount + " instance of com");
      if(domainOtherCount != 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + domainOtherCount + " instances of other domains");
      if(domainOtherCount == 1)
        System.out.println(">> Found " + domainOtherCount + " instance of other domains");
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It's not outputting the correct things, and I have done everything I can think of to try and fix it. I was hoping that someone else could look it over and make some suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) Clarify exactly what the problem is.  Please be more specific than "I'm not getting the right output".  2) Consider breaking "main()" into different methods.  3) Consider putting your URL types (http, https, etc) into an array or list.  IMHO..

Comment: That's not how this site works. You tell us the expected output and your actual output. You also debug the program to find out where it's not going as you would expect. We can then help with those details.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the problem. It's my first time using this website, so if you need more details I can try to provide them.